# Can UTxO sit at a minting policy (currency symbol), like at a validator script address?

Tags: on-chain

Both minting policy and validator script are on-chain code. Validator script can be used to lock fund sitting at its validator script address. A transaction can consume the UTxO only if the validator script successfully passes the validation.

Is it possible for an UTxO sitting at a minting policy (i.e. its currency symbol), so that a transaction that successfully consumes the UTxO by passing the minting policy can mint some native tokens?

My understanding is no because minting policy is only a part of a minting transaction but is not supposed to be the script address of an UTxO. Minting native tokens does not work the same as consuming an UTxO sitting at a script address. But I am not sure about my understanding.

Hope someone could help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, minting policies is part of a transaction and and is not part of a script address UTxO, so it doesn't make sense saying "UTxO sitting at a minting policy", since the minting policy simply allows the minting / burning of native assets or not, it doesn't sit anywhere.

The answer to your question, though, is unexpected. You can create a minting policy that only validates if a certain script is being consumed. You would just need to confirm (in the minting policy) that a certain script is present in the input.